# Referencing next class in template class, gettng error "expected ';'"

Tags: c++

I am getting the following when trying to compile the code below:

```
preallocarray.h: In member function 'void PreallocArray<T>::push_back(const T&)':
preallocarray.h:82: error: expected `;' before 'itr'
```

I have a nested const_iterator class inside of my LinkedList class I created.  It's been many years since I've done C++, so this is probably caused by something silly, but I've been hacking around and googling for an hour with no luck...

Here's my linked list class definition, decared in linklist.h:

```
template <typename T> 
class LinkedList 
{
    <snip...>
    public:
        class const_iterator
        {
        <snip...>
        };
    <snip...>
};
```

Then I have a second class, declared in preallocarray.h, as follows:

```
#include "linklist.h"
template <typename T>
class PreallocArray
{
    <snip...>
    public:
        void push_back( const T & newValue )
        {
            if (capacity == size)
            {
                allocateNode( capacity / 2 );
            }
            LinkedList<Node>::const_iterator itr; // error occurs here
            theList.end();
        }
    <snip...>

    private:
        LinkedList<Node> theList; // the linked list of nodes
    <snip...>
};
```

Comment: That is very strange. I see you left out a bit of code, could you edit in the rest? The code snippets that you showed here look completely correct.

Comment: Sure. I was just afraid that would obfuscate the problem. Note, when I comment out the line indicating where the error occurs, the error does go away...  Also, I have tested the const_iterator and LinkedList classes separately.

Comment: When the error occurs here `LinkedList<Node>::const_iterator itr`, what is `Node`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LinkedList<Node>::const_iterator itr; // error occurs here
```

Based on the fact the enclosing class is *actually* a class template, I suspect that you intended to write `T` instead of `Node`.  What is `Node` by the way? And where is it defined?

If you really wanted to write `T`, then you've to write it as:

```
typename LinkedList<T>::const_iterator itr;
```

Don't forget to write `typename` as I've written above. If you've to write `typename` even if the template parameter is `Node` but its definition depends on `T` in some way:

```
typename LinkedList<Node>::const_iterator itr;//if Node depends on T
```

To know why `typename` is needed, see this answer by *@Johannes Schaub*:

- [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names/613132#613132)

Comment: Even if he did mean to write `Node`, if the definition of `Node` depends on `T` your answer is still correct.

Comment: The missing `typename` was the problem.  I changed it to `typename LinkedList<Node>::const_iterator itr;`, and it works!  Thanks!  Note, Node was declared further up as a struct in the PreallocArray.

Comment: @squawknull: Well my guess is right. Now accept the answer :P

Comment: Just to explain why this is: because `Node` is dependant on the template parameter (in this case because it's nested in the template class), the compiler does not know what specialization `LinkedList<Node>` will expand to until the `PreallocArray` template itself is instantiated, so it doesn't know for sure whether `LinkedList<T>::const_iterator` denotes a type (it could be a static member - or not exist at all - in some specialisations), so you have to explicitly inform the compiler that you want to treat it as a type name.

Comment: @Sven: Gave the link to the explanation by *@Johannes Schaub*. I think he has explained it beautifully. :-)